# How can I safely migrate from google_project_iam_policy resources to google_project_iam_member?

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

I have a TF project which currently uses a single `google_project_iam_policy` resource, and would like to transition to using 
`google_project_iam_member`.

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_iam.html) warns:

> google_project_iam_policy cannot be used in conjunction with google_project_iam_binding and google_project_iam_member or they will fight over what your policy should be.

Is there a safe path to migrate from one style to the other?

Answer (score 3):

`google_project_iam_policy` might fight with `google_project_iam_binding` and `google_project_iam_member`, but it should be possible to use them concurrently for a brief period (provided they contain the same values).

I haven't tested this, but I think it should be possible to do something like:

1. Mirror the current `google_project_iam_policy` permissions into a new set of `google_project_iam_binding` or `google_project_iam_member` resources
2. Run `terraform apply` to add the new resources to your terraform state file
3. Remove the old `google_project_iam_policy` resources from your terraform config, but don't run `terraform apply`
4. Run `terraform state rm <resource-name>` for each of the old `google_project_iam_policy` resources
5. Run `terraform plan` and confirm no changes are planned